# HPQC 12.53 - Error While Raising a Defect From a Failed Test Step

Tags: hp-quality-center

I am getting the following error while trying to raise a defect for a failed test step: **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"**.

This error is observed from all test cases that were uploaded using ALM Excel Add In. But for any other test cases that were manually created this error is not observed.

We are using HPQC 12.53 version. HP ALM Add In is also for version 12.53.

I have checked the Registry value per this link's suggestion (https://community.hpe.com/t5/Quality-Center-ALM-Practitioners/Object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-quot-QC-to/td-p/5711671), however, the relevant registry already has the correct value.

Hoping for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the reason of the above error message. When testers uploaded test cases using HP's Excel Add In, a required field called "Type" was left to have no value. Surprising part for me was that HPQC didn't have any complaint about the empty Type field and happily uploaded test cases. The problem arose when these test cases were executed from test lab and the null reference error message was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

If 'Type' is empty, you can fill in 'Manual' for manual test case using Find & replace functionality. It should work fine.